# mail.perform_deliveries = false doesn't work in an ActionMailer interceptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

We're using an ActionMailer interceptor like this:

```
class MailerInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    p 1
    if message.to.include?("test2@example.com")
      p 2
      message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end
end

Mailer.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)
```

But it doesn't seem to block sending of messages to that address in production or in our test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "MailerInterceptor" do
  it "should block sending to certain addresses" do
    expect{ Mailer.user_alert("test1", "test@example.com").deliver }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    expect{ Mailer.user_alert("test2", "test2@example.com").deliver }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }
  end
end
```

This is with rails 3.2.14.

It prints '2' on the second line of the test, but still delivers the email.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `Mailer.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)` it should be something like    `ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)`

Comment: also try `mesage.delivery_method = :test` instead of `message.perform_deliveries = false`

Answer (score 9):

Please check if you are using `ActionMailer #delivery` method and not `#delivery!` because second one skips checking perform_deliveries.

Comment: Does this refer to the `.deliver`and `.deliver!` methods (not `delivery`?)

Comment: Yes it does! And even if the docs don't seem to mention it, its true!

Answer (score 1):

There is some more details required in your code although I can suggest some thing that may be help you

```
    Mailer.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)
```

it should be

```
   ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)
```

Secondly your `message.perform_deliveries = false` should work do not know why it is not working

you can simply try

```
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
```

instead of

```
  message.perform_deliveries = false
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` change it for all messages?  I only want to block sending this particular message.  Thx for the response!

Comment: I tried changing to `ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailerInterceptor)` but it didn't seem to make a difference.

`message.delivery_method = :test` gives `undefined method 'delivery_method=' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fd05d0d7f20>`.

My hack for now has been to do `message.to = "junk@mydomain.com"` - this still sends it, but at least does not spam the user.  It'd be a lot cooler if it didn't send at all though.  Thanks!